# Javascript prototyping inheritance

Tags: javascript

I want to know why does child scope create a new property when using literal type like string  and it does not create a  new object when using  object notation below example will clarify

```
paretscope.aString = 'parent string'

//now initialize a string in child scope so it will create a new property in child scope
childScope.aString = 'child string'

paretscope.model={key:"abc"}

// now i modify an object property in child scope but it will not create
// a new object in child scope instead it will modify object in parent scope

childscope.model.key ="xyz"
```

Comment: The example doesn't clarify anything to me.

Comment: I'm just as lost. Are you using a library? `model` is not standard `JS`. What are you expecting to happen, and what's happening instead?

Comment: I see no relationship between `paretscope` (`parentScope`?) and `childScope`...

Comment: is `parentScope` the prototype of `childScope`?
a little more of code would be quite helpful

Comment: childscope(fiction name) is inherited from parent scope i just want to understand this concept

Comment: parentscope is prototype of childscope

Comment: so there you go, when you add a property to `childScope.model` you are actually adding a property to `childScope`'s prototype's property `model`
-> `childScope.model === Object.getPrototypeOf(childScope).model && childScope.model === parentScope.model`

Comment: but aString  is also present in parent scope

Comment: you're directly setting a new valiue in `childScope.aString = 'child string'` and on `childScope.model.key` you are modifying the shadowed Object `model` you'd need to replace `childScope.model = {...}` for `childScope` to have an own property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem does not have anything to do with primitive values or objects/arrays. It's a matter of *how* exactly you are accessing/modifying the property <sup>[1]</sup>.

In

```
childScope.aString = 'child string'
```

you are **assigning a new value** to the property `aString`. This will *create* the property on the `childScope` element if it does not exist yet. Whether `childScope` has an *inherited* property with that name does not matter, when you do an assignment, the property is always created on the object itself.

In

```
childScope.model.key ="xyz"
```

you are **not** assigning a new value to the property, you are adding a property to the value itself, which is something totally different.

The equivalent process to the string assignment would be to assign a new object to the `model` property.

```
childScope.model = {key:"xyz"}
```

---

1: It is a bit related to mutable and immutable data types though. All primitive values in JavaScript are immutable, i.e. to modify a value, you have to create a new value. Arrays and objects are mutable though, so you can add elements/properties, without creating a new array or object.

So, values of immutable data types *force* you to assign a new value to a property/variable, while values of mutable data types can be modified in place.